# c#winforms, ограничение доступа к форме

Tags: c#

есть 10 форм для 10 отделов,  нужно чтобы по базе данных пользователей по строку depertament ограничить доступ конкретным формам конкретным отделам, при регистрация логин и пароль юзеров заливается в одну таблицу базы данных. ниже выложил код и пикчу. помогите пожалуйста разобраться новичку!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;


namespace LOCAL_PROJECT
{
public partial class login : Form
{
    public login()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection();
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
    }

    private void login_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //ПОДСКАЗКА ЛОГИН ПАРОЛЬ
        textBox1.Text = "Login";
        textBox1.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
        textBox1.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        Font myfont = new Font("Times new Roman", 18);
        textBox1.Font = myfont;
        textBox2.Text = "Password";
        textBox2.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
        textBox2.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        Font myfont1 = new Font("Times new Roman", 18);
        textBox2.Font = myfont1;

        etraplar etraplar22 = new etraplar();
        etraplar22.textuser.Text = textBox1.Text;

    }

    private void textBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       textBox1.Text = null;
       textBox1.ForeColor = Color.Black;
       
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }

    private void textBox2_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox2.Text = null;
        textBox2.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    }

   
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string user = textBox1.Text;
            string pass = textBox2.Text;
           
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("server = 192.168.1.199; UserId = admin; Password = 12345; database = Employee");

            MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("select count(*) FROM register where login = '" + textBox1.Text + "' and parol = '" + textBox2.Text + "'", conn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            //  if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
          //  {
                string dol = GetDoljnost("login", "parol");

                if (dol == "STA")
                {
                Form2 form22 = new Form2();
                    this.Hide();
                    form22.Show();
                }
               
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error password", "alter", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

                }
           // }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("password does not match");

        }

        

    }

    public string GetDoljnost(string login, string parol)
    {
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("server = 192.168.1.199; UserId = admin; Password = 12345; database = telecom");
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select TOP 1 department FROM register WHERE login = '" + login + "',  AND parol = '" + parol + "'", conn);
        
        //    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@login", login);
        //    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parol", parol);
        using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            reader.Read();
            return reader.GetString(0);
        }
    }
}
```

}

пикча общего меню где должен быть ограничение button, тоесть по этим button-ам осуществляется переход формам.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

пикча таблицы базы данных пользователей
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: так в чем вопрос проблема? как правильно права раздать?

Comment: да , допустим пользователь через форму логин пароль логинлся  в форму меню, после этот пользователь по поле логина (лучше конечно по поле depertament в базе данных  пользователей ) имел доступ именно конкретному форму

Comment: Ну если по тупому. При нажатии на кнопку сделать запрос в таблицу пользователей и проверить принадлежит ли текущий пользователь этому отделу.  например на кнопку1 проверитб depatment = administrative  если пользователь в administrative то пустить На кнопку2 проверить отдел например economist .

Comment: как мне видится нужно создать  условия  проверки и повесить на button_click. возможно я не прав . если логика верна, то как создать ... может кто то поможет ?

Comment: Я бы сделал по другому. Сделал бы таблицу ролей.  К имеющейся вашей. Пользователь = роль  Типа роль ROL_ADMINDEPT. B И прописывал бы в роль пользователей. Тогда было бы записей больше но более гибко настроить можно. Бывает так что человек кого-то подменяет из другого отдела и нужно пустить в определенный объект но не в отдел.  Даем роль на объект(в вашем случае кнопка) и пускаем любого пользователя у которого есть роль на объект.

Comment: да на каждую кнопку повесить SQL запрос по критериям и проверить подходит нет. В зависимости от этого пускаем или не пускаем.

Comment: задача усложняется тем что все пользователи не зависимо от отделов находятся в одной таблице .

Comment: это не усложнение. так и должно быть.  Отдел лишь параметр

Comment: Вам в любом случае нужно на клик каждой кнопки прописать запрос в базу на предмет наличия прав дальнейшего выполнения программы.   Сделать обработку 10 button кликов  и там уже проверить некой функцией с параметром отдел пользователь можно ли продолжить работу.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Я бы делал так
            Допустим ваши 10 кнопок 10 отделов. 
            ROL_DEPT1....  ROL_DEPT10
            
            Таблица пользователей.
            
            Имя USERNAME   
            ...... остальные данные 
            например dbuser1 
            
            Таблица ролей  ROLS
            ROLNAME
            USERNAME
            
            Данные
            ROLNAME        USERNAME
            -----------    -----------
            ROL_DEPT1      dbuser1 
            
            
            При нажатии на кнопку1 проверяем есть ли в таблице ROLS запись при которой 
            ROLNAME  = USERNAME  
            а именно ROL_DEPT1 = dbuser1
            если есть пускаем
            если нет не пускаем.
            
        на кнопку 2 аналогично проверяем 
            ROL_DEPT2 = dbuser1

Если строго по задаче. Без таблицы ROLS.
Ну проверяйте SQL запросом на каждую кнопку есть ли человек в отделе  
для кнопки1 отдел1  ....... для кнопки10 отдел10
```

Добавлено
У Вас в обработке нажатия на кнопку должно быть так примерно

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         if accessPermision("login","dept") == true  {
            ...доступ разрешен делаем что нужно (вызываем нужный метод)
         {
          else  MessageBox.Show("В доступе отказано");
    }
 private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         if accessPermision("login","dept3") == true  {
            ...доступ разрешен делаем что нужно (вызываем нужный метод)
         {
          else  MessageBox.Show("В доступе отказано");
    }
```

a в методе accessPermision  делаем запрос на проверку.

Comment: если без этого меню прямиком сделать переход на нужную форму по sql запросу ?

Comment: ну да именно так.  Если запрос вернул условно true по вашему условию  то пустить иначе не пустить.

Comment: если щас выложу код запроса можете поправить меня ?

Comment: Выкладывайте. Но я уже с работы уезжаю. И буду у компа вечером поздно. Думаю тут найдется тот кто подправит.

Comment: я очень надеюсь на это !  спасибо вам большое за отклик ! но вопрос пока не закрою с вашего позволения !)

Comment: Да без разницы. Вам всеголишь нужно проверить на каждую кнопку соответствует ли соответствующий(кнопке) отдел текущему пользователю. ВСЕ!  Это если по простому условию вашей задаче.

Comment: ввел кое-какие изменения , пожалуйста поправьте меня кто-нибудь

Comment: с точки зрения направления вы суть поняли. По кнопке button2 вы проверяете является ли пользователь в должности STA и если да то  выполняете действие на кнопку button2.  Так же прописываете на все остальные кнопки. НО!!. Сам код и подход очень ужасен. Сама проверка должна быть в максимум один if в 3-4 строчки. А проверка вынесена в отдельный метод.  Не нужно конекшин создавать в каждой кнопке. Конекшин создается и проверяется в при запуске приложения.  А потом используется для всех запросов. Тут надо еще много поработать. Но с правами мысль вы уловили.

Comment: благодарю ! проверка по SQL запрос насколько не правильно можете сказать ?  проверку вывел в отдельный метод , на button2 объявил этот метод но никаких действий не происходит, хочу понят где именно не правильно написан код.

Comment: Добавил в ответ как  ПРИМЕРНО организовать проверку по нажатию на кнопки отделов и проверки на права. Согласно вашему тз.  Обратить внимание на параметры метода accessPermision